# How are remisiers in Malaysia and Singapore different from stock brokers in other countries?

Tags: stocks, terminology, broker, singapore, malaysia

In Singapore and Malaysia, some (most?) investors buy stocks through a "remisier". Remisiers are apparently special enough to get their own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remisier):

> A remisier (also known as a Commissioned Dealer's Representative) is an agent of a stockbroking company and receives a commission for each transaction handled (as compared with a paid dealer's representative, who is a direct employee of a stockbroking company and whose remuneration structure is based on a fixed monthly salary). Although the origin of the word is French ("remisier" means "an intermediary"), and although remisiers are still a feature of the Paris Bourse, the term is now most commonly used in the context of the Kuala Lumpur Stock Exchange (or Bursa Malaysia) and the Singapore Stock Exchange.

How do remisiers differ from stock brokers? Don't stock brokers (especially block trade brokers) in other countries earn commissions based on the volume of transaction they facilitate too? Are remisiers merely a type of stock broker?